# Page is always empty when using UIPageViewController in UINavigationController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a storyboard that starts with a `UINavigatonController`. The `rootViewController` is pointed to a `UIViewController` which has a button on it. The button segues (push) to a `UIPageViewController`.

When `UIPageViewController` loads I programmatically create views of the pages (defined by another view controller in a xib file).

When I run the application, clicking the button transitions as expected but the resulting view is always empty (just black screen). It seems like I am missing something very obvious but after couple of days I seek help!

Here is the code for viewDidLoad for `UIPageViewController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Create the content
    [self createContentPages];

    //Set the initial view controllers.

    NSDictionary *options = 
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
    [NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin]
                            forKey: UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey];

    self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] 
                       initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl
                       navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                       options: options];

    pageController.dataSource = self;

    ContentViewController *contentViewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContentViewController" bundle:nil];
    contentViewController.dataObject = [self.pageContent objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:contentViewController];

    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers 
                                  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                   animated:NO 
                                 completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageController.view];
    [self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];    

    //Assign the gestureRecognizers property of our pageViewController to our view's  gestureRecognizers property.
    self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageController.gestureRecognizers;
}
```

Comment: I knew it was something obvious. My class for the view of the content was also set as UIPageViewController (duh!).